# jQuery multi-ticker show/hide flickering

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide, ticker

I have three tickers that I'm cycling through using jQuery. It's working well, but the problem I'm left with is a slight flicker each time the ticker is switched. Does anyone know what the issue could be here? Is this something wildly simple that I'm missing?

**Fiddle:**
 https://jsfiddle.net/3yhaynpz/7/

**jQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var tick1 = $(".tick1");
var tick2 = $(".tick2");
var tick3 = $(".tick3");

tick2.hide();
tick3.hide();

cycle();
function cycle(){
    if (tick1.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick1.hide();
        tick2.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick1 ul li').length * 1000);

    else if (tick2.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick2.hide();
        tick3.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick2 ul li').length * 1000);

    else if (tick3.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick3.hide();
        tick1.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick3 ul li').length * 1000);
}
});
```

Comment: looks like the animation of the height from 20px to 38px is causing the flicker.

Comment: Yeah, if you manually set the heights in function visHeight(anim) to "38px" rather than using the calculated height, the flicker goes away.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out what's wrong with the height calculations.  Or you can just use css to set the heights manually.  Here's a fiddle with my workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/3yhaynpz/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the script you're using is setting a height of `38px` on the elements *while* animating them, and then a height of `20px` prior to the animation. In doing so, the flicker that you're seeing is occurring.

The simplest solution would be to specify a `min-height` of `38px` on the `.tickerwrap` elements.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5sgy9c7z/)

```
.tickerwrap {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Did exactly what I needed it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: none;`, use the CSS property `visibility: hidden;`. That way, the space will always be taken up by the invisible element.